# web2py routing for all controllers?

Tags: python, mod-rewrite, url-routing, web2py

i want something like this using web2py routing :

- domain.com/App/controller/view/args?profile Id=XX
- domain.com/App/profile Id/controller/view/args

i try this code :

```
routes_in = (
    ('/App-name/(?P<any>.*)/$c/$f/', '/App-name/$c/$f/\g<any>'),
)
routes_out = (
    ('/App-name/$c/$f/\g<any>', '/App-name/(?P<any>.*)/$c/$f/'),
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**its work now**

```
routes_in = (
('/admin','/admin'),
('/admin/$anything','/admin/$anything'),
('/$app/appadmin','/$app/appadmin'),
('/$app/appadmin/$anything','/$app/appadmin/$anything'),
('/Appname/$profileid/','/Appname/default/index/$profileid'),
('/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/','/Appname/$c/$f/$profileid'),
('/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/$arg1','/Appname/$c/$f/$arg1/$profileid'),
('/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/$arg1/$arg2','/Appname/$c/$f/$arg1/$arg2/$profileid'),
)
routes_out = (
('/admin','/admin'),
('/admin/$anything','/admin/$anything'),
('/$app/appadmin','/$app/appadmin'),
('/$app/appadmin/$anything','/$app/appadmin/$anything'),
('/Appname/default/index/$profileid','/Appname/$profileid/'),
('/Appname/$c/$f/$profileid','/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/'),
('/Appname/$c/$f/$arg1/$profileid','/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/$arg1'),
('/Appname/$c/$f/$arg1/$arg2/$profileid','/Appname/$profileid/$c/$f/$arg1/$arg2'),
)
```